# MS Project VBA: Loop All Open .MPP, Print PDF

Tags: vba, loops, pdf, ms-project

Goal: VBA macro that will loop through all open projects, apply 3 different views, and PDF them.  Presently, the code below applies the correct views (filters etc), and does a save as, but I have to click ok twice to confirm the location and over-write the existing. Second, I thought about using Set SecondProject = ActiveProject, but there are three of us on the team and we don't all own the same number of projects.  MS Project seems to be just different enough that the examples I find for other applications don't work. In the interest of simplifying, I'll include one of the report views below rather than all 3.

Primary questions:
1) How do I loop through all open projects
2) How do I make it skip the ok steps in save as (is there another way to print to PDF)

Current code is below:

```
Dim FirstProject As Project
Dim SecondProject As Project

Dim targetFolder As String
```

targetFolder = "C:\Users\522842\Desktop\Community Care Transformation\1. Deliverables"

```
Set FirstProject = ActiveProject

ViewApply Name:="VA Status"
FilterApply Name:="&All Tasks"
FilterApply Name:="Active Tasks"
FilePrint FromPage:=1
FileSaveAs "C:[path here].pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to loop through all open projects and export to PDF format retaining the project name and appending the ".PDF" extension:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim P As Project
    Dim ProjectFullName As String
    Dim PDFname As String
    Dim DotPos As Integer
    For Each P In Projects
        P.Activate
        'Add code here to apply views and filters as required
        ProjectFullName = P.FullName
        DotPos = InStr(ProjectFullName, ".")
        If DotPos > 0 Then ProjectFullName = Left(ProjectFullName, DotPos - 1)
        PDFname = ProjectFullName & ".PDF"
        DocumentExport FileName:=PDFname
    Next P
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this option.

The result when I run this is that it renames the MS Project file, but does not actually print to PDF.  

Any ideas?  

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We got it working (note the reference to user specific fields which would need to be modified.

```
Sub PrintThisFile()

Dim Names As String

Names = ActiveProject.Name                                                                                                                                                 'Read in file name
Names = Replace(Names, ".mpp", "")                                                                                                                                                                      'Get rid of .mpp extension
FilePageSetupPage PaperSize:=pjPaperTabloid
ViewApply Name:="VA Status"                                                                                                                                                                             'Set VA Status View
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterApply Name:="&All Tasks"                                                                                                                                                                          'Clears existing filter
FilterApply Name:="Active Tasks"                                                                                                                                                                        'Set the Active Filter to prepare the full schedule for printing
DocumentExport FileName:="C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Community Care Transformation\1. Deliverables\" & Names & ".pdf"                                             'Saves the document as a pdf *MUST CHANGE DESTINATION FOLDER ACCORDINGLY
FilterApply Name:="VA 2 Week"                                                                                                                                                                           'Apply the 2 week look ahead view
DocumentExport FileName:="C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Community Care Transformation\1. Deliverables\" & Names & "_Two Week Look Ahead.pdf"       'Saves the 2 week look ahead document as a pdf *MUST CHANGE DESTINATION FOLDER ACCORDINGLY
FilterApply Name:="VA Only Status Due"                                                                                                                                                      'Apply the Only Status Due view
DocumentExport FileName:="C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Community Care Transformation\1. Deliverables\" & Names & "_Due Next Week.pdf"                   'Saves the document as a pdf
ViewApply Name:="VA Status"                                                                                                                                                                             'Reset to VA Status View
FilterApply Name:="&All Tasks"
FilterApply Name:="Active Tasks"
PaneClose           


MsgBox ("Documents have been saved")

End Sub
```